# opera css3 transitions ignoring timer? - bug or feature?

Tags: css, opera, transition

did a small animated experimental menu over here http://jsfiddle.net/NWvSQ/1/

In Opera, when you hover out of an item, the border radius changes back immediately (item becomes square-ish for a second), rather than being animated. Seems ok in Chrome and Firefox.

Is that a bug or feature please? Any fix available?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a known bug, CORE-35614 'apply transition to border-radius and box-shadow' to be specific (though Opera's bug tracker is closed so you can't see it). No ETA on the fix yet.